# Sign in with Apple issue. Error Domain=AKAuthenticationError Code=-7003

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sign-in-with-apple, apple-login

In my iOS app when I trying to Sign in with apple I
got this error {Error Domain=AKAuthenticationError Code=-7003 "(null)" UserInfo={AKClientBundleID=com.*******}}.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVSvq.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/crKvO.jpg)

All below points been checked

1. In Target > Signin & Capabilities I add Sign in with apple.
2. In my profile I selected "Sign In with Apple".
3. Edit scheme I  try to debug mode, but got same error.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.